# What does <X> mean in java method declarations?

Tags: java, generics

I'm looking through `EntityManager.java` and I see

```
public <T extends Object> T find(Class<T> type, Object o, LockModeType lmt, Map<String, Object> map);
```

I've never seen `<X>` type declarations within a class method definition.  What does this mean?

`public <T extends Object> T find(` seems like it's defining that T will extend another class.  Am I understanding that this requires you to extend another object?

Comment: It's called "generics" and is a lot like C++ template classes (but different) ... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: Info on generic methods specifically: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: Obligatory Angelika Langer link: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedMethods.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public <T extends Number> T find()
```

This means that you define a [generic](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf) function, which has a type parameter denoted by T for the sake of definition. T has to be a subclass (extends) of Number. The function returns an object of type T.

Then you can call the function like that:

```
Double d = find();
Integer i = find();
```

but you the following is a compile time error:

```
String s = find();  //error
```

because String doesn't extend Number.

Comment: I like this answer a lot as it explains some details about generics in Java, like `<T extends Object>` behavior

Answer (score 0):

This is the use of "Generics", introduced with Java 5.  An overview is available at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java .

Answer (score 0):

This java generic type.

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html