# Difference between having and not having <T> before declaring return value of a method

Tags: java, generics

What is difference between

```
public static<V> List<V> myMethod(V v){ return new ArrayList<V>();}
```

and

```
public static List<V> myMethod(V v){ return new ArrayList<V>();}
```

What does `<V>` before the declaration of return type in method 1 means?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Comment: Simpler questions have been asked and answered here on StackOverflow, why the downvote? Plus: Probably a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381018/what-does-x-mean-in-java-method-declarations?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is simple:

- The first one compiles
- The second one doesn't compile

The reason the 2nd one doesn't compile is that `V` has not been declared.

The only way the second one would compile is if the method wasn't static and the class had a generic parameter `V`, thus declaring it for all instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

In the 1st method, `V` is a type parameter of the method.

In the 2nd method, `V` is a class or interface type.

Comment: pls provide example or point me to some other site that provides good example and explanation. I find hard time googling this.

Comment: the 2nd method is a normal method, so `V` must be a "normal" type, i.e. a class or an interface. The first method is a "generic method", so you need to learn about Java generics.